# Does the relation $\mid^*$ have any interesting applications for understanding the structure of commutative rings that aren't integral domains?

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question, definition

There is a binary relation $\mid^*$ defined on any commutative ring as follows: $a \mid^* b$ iff $ak=b$ for some $k \in R$ that is not a zero divisor. This is always transitive, and it is reflexive except on the trivial ring. We also have: $$(*) \qquad x \mid^* 0 \rightarrow x=0.$$

Now in an integral domain, the relation $\mid^*$ almost completely agrees with the more usual $\mid$, with the exception that whereas $x \mid 0$ is always true, nonetheless by $(*)$ the statement $x \mid^* 0$ is never true for $x \neq 0$.

However in other commutative rings it can behave differently. For a simple example, observe that whereas $1 \mid x$ is always true, nonetheless $1 \mid^* x$ is equivalent to $x$ not being a zero-divisor. For another example of how they can diverge, observe that in $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, we have $(1,1,0) \mid (1,0,0)$. But it can't be the case that $(1,1,0) \mid^* (1,0,0)$. In general, I think that $\mid^*$ behaves much more like an equivalence relation than $\mid$ does. Its almost as if $a \mid^* b$ is 25% of the way to saying that there exists a unit $u$ such that $au=b$.

> **Soft Question.** Does the relation $\mid^*$ have any interesting applications for understanding the structure of commutative rings that aren't integral domains? If so, what are some examples of not-entirely trivial applications of $\mid^*$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I don't quite know what you mean, but I've changed it to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ to better illustrate.

Comment: Basically, in any ring, it is true that if $a\mid^* 0$ then $a=0$. You first illustrate this in $\mathbb Z$, then you illustrate it in $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. That isn't "different."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, good point. I fixed it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, and stuffed it up. But *now* I think I fixed it :)

Comment: This gives a disconnected poset, which is interesting. For example, $\mathbb Z$ has two components, while $\mathbb Z^n$ has $2^n$ components. $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ has $\tau(n)$ components. In all cases, there is a natural order amongst the components when you consider them under the standard $\mid$ relation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, true! Unfortunately it agrees with the relation of being "strong associates" (existence of a unit) on any finite commutative ring , so we have to go to infinite ones if we're to see anything interesting.

Comment: It doesn't quite equate to existence of units. $2$ and $3$ are in the same component in $\mathbb Z$, for example. Rather, it is strong associates on the localization of the ring against the set of non-zero divisors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, pretty sure every non-zero divisor in a finite ring is a unit. Let $x \in R$ be a non-zero divisor and assume $R$ is finite. Consider the map $x \mapsto xy$. Since $x$ is a non-zero divisor, hence $x$ is cancellative, so this map is injective. By finiteness, it is surjective. So there exists $y$ such that $xy=1$. Thus $x$ is a unit.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't talking only about finite rings. Didn't notice that you had specified that. @goblin

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, haha okay.